# Как сделать вертикальный нав бар в Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Хочу сделать нав бар как на картинке (мой дизайн из Figma)

[image: Вертикальный нав бар]
Возможно ли?

Comment: https://bootstraptema.ru/stuff/snippets_bootstrap/menu/vertical_accordion_menu_md/24-1-0-1816

Comment: Да, с помощью Bootstrap (https://bootstrap-4.ru/), сделай 1 столбик в разметке, и туда просто кидай div этих блоков, они сразу будут в столбик.